# Логическая ошибка(Не соответствие задумке)

Tags: python

[image]

Когда я определил и вызвал все соответствующие функции, а также определил список, копию списка и список с двумя предыдущими, я ожидал сначала блок информации с приставкой "Great", а за тем и все остальное(т.е обработанный список-оригинал)

Comment: Вставьте код текстом

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `==` не проверяет, что объект является тем же самым, он просто проверяет, что два объекта равны. А у вас список-оригинал и список-копия действительно равны.

Теоретически, вы можете заменить в ваших проверках `==` на `is` - оно как раз-таки проверяет что это тот же самый объект. Но вообще строить логику на `is` не рекомендуется, т.к. интерпретатор может кэшировать некоторые значения, и представлять в памяти одним и тем же объектом значения, для которых вы можете не ожидать этого.

Если вы хотите точно идентифицировать ваши объекты и строить логику на их идеинтичности, то нужно внутри них в какой-то форме хранить некий идентификатор и сравнивать по нему.